# Are there any rules that specify a class' alignment?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

After a [brief discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11/2015/8/12) about the topic, (which didn't really go anywhere), I was wondering if there was anything in the rules that determined whether certain classes *must* have particular alignments? (E.g. Paladins *must* be Lawful-Good to Lawful-Neutral)

Is there a difference in Editions?

Comment: What is the reason for the negative score? Helps to know why certain questions are voted down.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but I personally downvoted because "this question does not show research effort."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each edition has different rules with respect to this. D&D 5e removed all restrictions and made alignment a general thing for characters. There is flavour text indicating which classes tend to do what, however the customization aspect allows for things like chaotic-evil Paladins.

For other editions, the easiest way to find out is to look up the class you're interested in and whatever edition you are playing.

For instance: Google search 3.5 Monk to find out that Monks need to be any lawful category.

As an example, D&D 3.5 has alignment rules for several classes such as Paladin, Barbarian and Druid.

Barbarians (any non-lawful); Paladins (lawful good); Druid (any neutral)

Comment: AD&D 1E & 2E had many alignment restrictions, assassins as any evil alignment got them removed from 2E. Thieves had to be non-lawful in 1E & 2E.